# Bash Rename delete specific string and set variables

Tags: bash

lets say there is are some files all containing abc in there name at the location of /home/user/my\ folder\

```
/home/user/my\ folder\testabcflie1 
/home/user/my\ folder\abctestfile2 
/home/user/my\ folder\testfileabc3
```

im trying to rename those file with out the abc in them all at once

```
/home/user/my\ folder\testflie1
/home/user/my\ folder\testfile2
/home/user/my\ folder\testfile3
```

this is what i have so far but it doesnt seem to do anything

```
DelStr="abc"
Folder="my\ folder"
dir=/home/user/$Folder
rename 's/\$DelStr//g' $dir/*
```

the rename script is a perl script that came with my raspberry pi.

Comment: Shell variables aren't expanded in single quotes.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: `$DelStr` is a shell variable. You're passing the string `\$DelStr` to `rename`, not the value of the variable.

Comment: how would i for mat the bit to send the variable when i take away the \ before it it says Global symbol "$DelStr" requires explicit package name at (user-supplied code).
p

Comment: Without \, `$DelStr` is interpreted as a variable by Perl that implements rename, but there's no such var. Use double quotes and no backslash. It might break, though, if the variable contains special characters.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should work for you.

Change directory to required directory & run this :

```
for f in $(ls); do mv -v $f ${f/abc/ }; done;
```

OR

```
rename abc '' *abc*
```

OR

```
for filename in ./*; do mv "./$filename" "./$(echo $filename | sed -e 's/abc//g')";  done
```

Comment: when running this code for f in $(ls); do mv -v $f ${f/abc/ }; done; it said 
mv: cannot stat ‘testfileabc’: No such file or directory

Comment: the rename abc '' *abc* say Bareword "abc" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at (user-supplied code).

Comment: It works fine, just executed it. You should first goto the required dir like : `cd /home/user/my\ folder\`. And then run the commands.

Comment: Try this : `rename "abc" "" *`